# Android drag and drop issue not displaying

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I'm working on a drag and drop application, everything is working fine but I saw an issue. I have 3 ImageViews, two of them are draggable objects and the other one is the drop target. Every time I drop the object in any location other than the drop target, it's totally disappearing!

Below is the code I used:

```
       ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initControls();

}

private void initControls() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView2);

    iv1.setTag("a");
    iv2.setTag("b");

    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView3);
    iv1.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    iv2.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    iv3.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

}

private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    //Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    //Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
          if(v != iv3)
              v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // Do nothing
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

        // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
        //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

        Drawable dropshadow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dropshadow);

        //view dragged item is being dropped on
        ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;

        //view being dragged and dropped
        ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

        /*
        //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
        Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();

        //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
        if(tag!=null)
        {
            //the tag is the view id already dropped here
            int existingID = (Integer)tag;
            //set the original view visible again
            findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        //set the tag in the target view to the ID of the view being dropped
        dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
        */


              String temp = "a";
              if(temp.equals(view.getTag())){
                  //dropped.setBackground(dropshadow);
                  dropTarget.setBackground(dropshadow);
                  Log.d(temp, "Correct Image");
              } else {
                  Log.d("b", "Wrong Image");
                  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }



        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```

What am I missing in here? Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I solved this myself. I added this method:

```
 private boolean dropEventNotHandled(DragEvent dragEvent) {
            return !dragEvent.getResult();
}
```

and added this:

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
           if (dropEventNotHandled(event)) 
              view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you start dragging - `motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` - you execute `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

But when you stop dragging, you don't do anything to the view. So I guess your view object is still invisible. Add a similar conditional statement to flip the visibility back to visible when the drag finishes.

Off the top of my head, assuming that MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is the end of a drag event, add the following after the first if block in your onTouch method

```
else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return true
}
```

Keep the final "else" block as well.

Comment: Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: See edits - but you should be able to work it out from your existing code and my comments.

Comment: Tried this one, but still it's not appearing.

Comment: Then you should have posted the full code and said "this isn't working, where have I gone wrong". Use the debugger to work out what is happening - is the onTouch event firing? is your code getting invoked but checking for the wrong action value? Is your code executing (including the setVisibility call) but the view isn't reappearing? Have you tried forcing a view refresh?

Comment: Actually, is the view passed in on the second call the same that was passed on the first? You might need to keep track of which view is being dragged so that when the onTouch event fires the second time, you're actually making the right view instance visible.

Comment: Yes. Dude I already solved my problem, looking back at the tutorial I found, I added this case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
         if (dropEventNotHandled(event)) 
         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      break;